# Where is CATALINA_BASE/webapps folder for Tomcat 8 on Mac?

Tags: java, macos, tomcat, catalina, tomcat8

I ran `brew install tomcat` to install tomcat 8.

Now I need to put my `.war` file in `CATALINA_BASE/webapps`

I cannot find that directory anywhere on my computer. How can I locate this folder so I can put my `.war` in there?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

use following command

```
$catalina -h
```

it will show the directories you need, alternatively you can upload war file using tomcat manager's web interface

Comment: that shows catalina_base = /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/8.0.9/libexec

But how can I navigate to there in finder?

Comment: You can use terminal to `cd` or open finder and press shift + command + g

Comment: the shift+command+g is a cool trick! it worked. Will accept after the obligatory 5 minutes has passed. Thanks!

Comment: You can also use `open <path>` from Terminal, or command-click the path from iTerm

Answer (score 15):

It should be installed here:

> /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/8.0.30/libexec/webapps

Replace `8.0.30` with your actual version. Hope this works!!